# OroCommerce Community Edition: How to completely change currency from USD to EUR?

Tags: orocommerce

I'm using OroCommerce Community Edition which supports single organization and single currency according to the oro website and that is ok for me, just need have Euro as that only currency.
Seems like the oro docs about currency is mostly for Enterprise edition and I there is no currency settings per organization in OroCE , so I was able to change only `System Configuration > General Setup > Currency` to Eur and that made weird results - order currency is Eur but product added as Usd and in order totals I have something like

```
Subtotal
  EUR150.00
  $150.00
Total
  EUR150.00
  $150.00
```

Probably the problem was in Default Price List for products which has both USD and Eur now (despite of OroCE should not support multitple currencies) and I didnt found how to remove USD from it. So I did fresh oro install, deleted that Default Price List and created new price list with Eur only, now it seems that I have only Eur for products and orders. But is it really all that need to do or maybe I missing something else?
Searching for USD in db I found

```
SELECT * FROM oro_plist_curr_combined

id  combined_price_list_id  currency
1   1                       USD
```

What is this table and why is it still contains USD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it possible, better reinstall application with base currency EUR. To do this you need to add     `currency: EUR` in the parameters.yml.

Comment: Do you have a documentation reference?

Comment: I can confirm that having currency: EUR  before running oro:install  changes all currency settings to EUR and no 'USD' found in db (except translation messages). But its really strange that such important thing isnt described in docs

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall orocommerce use link

https://vanderboon.net/2022/07/16/installing-orocommerce-community-5-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

---

If your base currency is not USD, you need to add your currency to parameters.yml. NOW! Edit **sudo nano ./config/parameters.yml**

Add the following line at the end:

currency: 'EUR'

Run the installer
php bin/console oro:install --env=prod --timeout=2000